# Welcome message and icon disappeared for Web Chat channel AZURE

Tags: azure, chatbot, web-chat

The chatbot style on the web channel changed from this:

[right version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XLIQj.png) (the left chat)
to this:
[different version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u6gl2.png) (still the left one)

to see the screenshots copy and paste manually in the browser

I do not know why but the web chat and direct line channels look the same now. How do I get the welcoming message and the icon on top again? This is the code in my HTML file:

```
<iframe style="height: 500px; width:350px;" src='https://webchat.botframework.com/embed/BOT_NAME?s=SECRET_FROM_WEB_CHAT'></iframe>
```

In the portal I have the bot details saved like this:
[link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V8SzA.png)

Any idea? Maybe I changed something accidentally?

Answer (score 0):

The one on the left is the old style I haven't seen in some years. The one on the right is the modern style. I think you got upgraded. Andy